# AWS EMR run spark job/step synchronously

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Is it possible to run/submit Spark Step synchronously?

I am trying to run the Spark step on AWS EMR cluster from Java App.

I am trying to implement a service that runs the job and returns the results. I am exploring client mode execution of AWS EMR. But not sure if thats the right answer. Any guidance or links would be great help.

High level workflow for api endpoint looks like this.

```
 /getMeStat -> add step to AWS EMR (EMR runs the job, generate result) -> returns results
```

Comment: Hmmm... this sounds wrong to me. Spark and EMR is not exactly build to be used as an http-request - rather it is build to process large amount of data in a parallel fashion which is usually a "heavy" operation that takes time. How about just letting your Java app start the EMR job and then return. Once the EMR job completes it can publish an event via SNS to notify your Java app (or any other program that cares) that the job is done and the app can update whatever is needed.

Comment: Thats the ultimate goal but I wanted to set up quick demo to get up and running quickly. I was looking into sync exe mode for Spark cluster and as Client deploy mode is Sync I thought that is something that would work for this case. But not sure How to corporate that with EMR and Java Jar

Comment: I would spend the 5 minutes on the simple event notification setup. You will have a quick demo up and running in no time at all.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt looking into Livy API