# Running code on JAVA app on AWS EMR Master as client mode

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am trying to run spark code on AWS EMR master node. But unable to configure the context on Master node.

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("testapp");
 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

I tried setMaster('yarn') and without master as well. But unable to get it running.

Is it even possible to run Spark code on master node as part of Java App. I have Spring Boot app running on Master node of AWS EMR cluster.

If I run this on another ec2 instance how do I configure this to run on EMR cluster?

```
@RequestMapping(
path = "/test/api",
method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public Integer testApi(
final HttpServletResponse response
) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("testApp");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("test.txt");
    JavaRDD<String> numbers = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+")).iterator());

    JavaRDD<String> validNumbers = numbers.filter(number -> !number.isEmpty());

    JavaRDD<Integer> intNumbers = validNumbers.map(number -> Integer.valueOf(number));

    return intNumbers.reduce((x, y) -> x + y);
}
```

Comment: What does "Unable to get it running" mean? Are you getting an error? What's the error?  For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman `Could not parse Master URL: 'yarn'`

Comment: Trying to achieve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052432/aws-emr-run-spark-job-step-synchronously

Comment: Are you installing Spark yourself or are you using EMR with the Spark application that AWS provides? If you use the AWS provided Spark application that is automatically installed when you spin up your cluster, you cannot run executors on the master node. You need a cluster of at least two machines to get the code running.

Comment: Yes. I have 1 master 3 slave machines

Comment: Trying to run spark code synchronously.